# classic view filter on managed metadata

Tags: sharepoint-online, filter, view, classic-experience

I need to keep one library in classic view and would like to occasionally create a view with a filter on a managed metadata column. Writing the item in the filter does not produce the desired result and not even using the unique identifier of the term.

Is there another easy way to create a filtered view on one term?

Answer (score 0):

Not possible with OOB functionality. A taxonomy column is a lookup under the covers, and you can't filter on lookups.

You could do it with code but you lose all the functionality of an OOB list view.

Answer (score 0):

Are you working in SharePoint online?

What is the template of the list?

Per my test, i can filter on managed metadata column.

If you are working with a task list, enable server rendering on the list view Web Part for the affected Tasks list.

Filtering doesn't work for Managed Metadata column in SharePoint Online Tasks list for your reference:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/troubleshoot/lists-and-libraries/managed-metadata-column-fails-filtering